# Inserting Windows Identity And HttpContext.User Into ASP.NET Application's Preload

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

I am trying to exercise some database code in my Models project in an ASP.NET MVC application, in a class derived from IProcessHostPreloadClient.Preload().

For those who are not familiar, this is a way for IIS to call a method in the application that serves as an application warm-up.

Not working and I think the problem is that running the database queries requires an authorized HTTPContext user or a Windows principal. So, I'm trying to fake the application into thinking there's an authorized user running this code.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Does this user has to be the end user of your application, or do you have some domain account configured in your database to make all calls from? If it is the first you are pretty much in a dead end because the `IProcessHostPreloadClient.Preload` method is not associated to any HttpContext. If it is the second you could configure the Application Pool of your application in IIS to run under this particular AD account.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov ASP.NET Impresonation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118(v=vs.71).aspx) could potentially run the application as the end user.

Comment: @LukeP, yes, of course, except that there's no such notion as *end user* in the `IProcessHostPreloadClient.Preload` method as I explained in my previous comment.